# How do I get my faceted search logic correct?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, faceted-search

I'm trying to create a faceted search so that my list items can be whittled down but my logic is definitely off. When I select a checkbox on a different filter, I need to reduce the results but I add them.

I've had a look for plugins to use but everything I could find uses old jQuery libraries that conflict with bootstrap.

I'm new to jQuery so please be kind.

Currently, I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);

    var someObj = {};
    someObj.idsGranted = [];
    someObj.idsDenied = [];

    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            someObj.idsGranted.push($(this).attr("id"));
            jQuery.each( someObj.idsGranted, function() {
                jQuery('li.'+this).addClass('granted');
            });
        } else {
            someObj.idsDenied.push($(this).attr("id"));
            jQuery.each( someObj.idsDenied, function() {
                jQuery('li.'+this).addClass('denied');
            });
        }
    });


    $count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    if ($count == '0') {
        jQuery('li.jobS').removeClass('granted');
        jQuery('li.jobS').removeClass('denied');
    };


    $('.reset').click(function() {
        $('input').attr('disabled', false);
        $('input').attr('checked', false);
        jQuery('li.jobS').removeClass('granted');
        jQuery('li.jobS').removeClass('denied');
    })
});
```

});

My efforts can be seen here:
http://79.170.40.40/newarthur.co.uk/find-a-job/